# How do I create a leaderboard from the stats in my Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a leaderboard in my app. The leaderboard should show the 10 best users who have the most high scores. My Firebase database looks like this:

Firebase Database:

[image: Firebase Database]

I have already created an activity with 10 TextViews one below the other. Starting with the first TextView I want to change the text to:

"1st place | 'username' | 'highscore' score"

Now my question:

What is the easiest way for me to do this?

Comment: You can not retrieve nested child data directly without passing it's key, I would suggest just retrieve data to specific limit then sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the top 10 users with the highest score, you can use a query like this:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
Query top10Query = usersRef.orderByChild("highscore").limitToLast(10);
```

Then read the matching data with something like this:

```
top10Query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("Firebase", userSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("Firebase", userSnapshot.child("highscore").getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

The above will give you the top 10 scores, but in ascending order as Firebase has no option to return results in descending order. To display them in the correct order, you'll need to reverse the results in your code, or add them to the UI in the inverse order.

Comment: Thanks very much! What is the easiest way to insert this into a linear layout? Is there an add() command ?

Comment: Did you try anything yet, either with the code from my answer, or on your own?

Comment: I used the code from your answer and it worked beautifully, but now I don't know the easiest way to add this to a layout.

Comment: This is the second time you ask for "the easiest way". Do you know of *any* way to do this? If so, show us what ways you know of, and we can help you pick the easiest, or improve on them. Otherwise you're asking us to help you find *any* way to do, and there are better places to learn that, for example by taking some [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+show+listview+from+firebase+realtime+database) and applying them to your own use-case. The [Firebase codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) is also a good place to start

Comment: I just found a solution for me. Now everything works. I'll take a look at Firebase Codelab, thank you.